# Orange Error when installing Network Add On

Tags: orange

[image: Orange Error Message]

Command failed: python python -m pip install Orange3-Network exited with non zero status

**Environment**
Windows 10
Python 3.7
Orange 3.17

**Detail Log Data**

```
Collecting Orange3-Network
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/86/78093ab58194619133289d1ffadc13a02ee3a61c479913b88fe8a7c2fa99/Orange3-Network-1.4.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-Network) (2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyqtgraph>=0.9.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-Network) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-Network) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Orange3>=3.3.9 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3-Network) (3.17.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.0->Orange3-Network) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: AnyQt>=0.0.8 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: bottleneck>=1.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.9.4 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keyring in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keyrings.alt in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-louvain in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.11)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.18.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.16.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: serverfiles in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (40.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd>=0.9.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from keyring->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from keyring->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from keyrings.alt->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (2.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from requests->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from requests->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\orange\lib\site-packages (from requests->Orange3>=3.3.9->Orange3-Network) (2.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: Orange3-Network
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Orange3-Network: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Orange3-Network: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Orange\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\norma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pjc_kbwm\\Orange3-Network\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\norma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-lp55jy4v --python-tag cp37:
  Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
  Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
  Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
  Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building extension "orangecontrib.network._fr_layout" sources
  build_src: building npy-pkg config files
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib
  copying orangecontrib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
  copying orangecontrib\network\community.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
  copying orangecontrib\network\network.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
  copying orangecontrib\network\readwrite.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
  copying orangecontrib\network\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
  copying orangecontrib\network\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\graphview.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxAnalysis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxClustering.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxExplorer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxFromDistances.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxSave.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\airtraffic.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\airtraffic_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\dicty_publication.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\dicty_publication_edges.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\dicty_publication_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm_all.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm_tags.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_genesets.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_genesets_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_pmid.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_pmid_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_huttenhower_a.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_huttenhower_a_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\makeNetworkList.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\mips_c2_cp_leu.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\mips_c2_cp_leu_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  copying orangecontrib\network\networks\network_info.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\button_autoscale.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\button_rect.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Category-Network.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_clear.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_HideSelection.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_Mark2Sel.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_Sel2Mark.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_SelisMark.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_UnselectedNodes.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkAnalysis.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkClustering.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkExplorer.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkFile.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkFromDistances.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkGenerator.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
  running build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  building 'orangecontrib.network._fr_layout' extension
  compiling C sources
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for Orange3-Network
  Running setup.py clean for Orange3-Network
Failed to build Orange3-Network
Installing collected packages: Orange3-Network
  Running setup.py install for Orange3-Network: started
    Running setup.py install for Orange3-Network: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Orange\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\norma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pjc_kbwm\\Orange3-Network\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\norma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-il4_hhwc\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    Warning: 'keywords' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building extension "orangecontrib.network._fr_layout" sources
    build_src: building npy-pkg config files
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib
    copying orangecontrib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
    copying orangecontrib\network\community.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
    copying orangecontrib\network\network.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
    copying orangecontrib\network\readwrite.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
    copying orangecontrib\network\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
    copying orangecontrib\network\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\graphview.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxAnalysis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxClustering.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxExplorer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxFile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxFromDistances.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\OWNxSave.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\airtraffic.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\airtraffic_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\dicty_publication.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\dicty_publication_edges.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\dicty_publication_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm_all.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\lastfm_tags.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_genesets.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_genesets_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_pmid.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_by_pmid_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_huttenhower_a.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\leu_huttenhower_a_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\makeNetworkList.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\mips_c2_cp_leu.net -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\mips_c2_cp_leu_items.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    copying orangecontrib\network\networks\network_info.tab -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\networks
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\button_autoscale.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\button_rect.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Category-Network.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_clear.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_HideSelection.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_Mark2Sel.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_Sel2Mark.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_SelisMark.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\Dlg_UnselectedNodes.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkAnalysis.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkClustering.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkExplorer.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkFile.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkFromDistances.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    copying orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons\NetworkGenerator.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\orangecontrib\network\widgets\icons
    running build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    building 'orangecontrib.network._fr_layout' extension
    compiling C sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Orange\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\norma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-pjc_kbwm\\Orange3-Network\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\norma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-il4_hhwc\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\norma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pjc_kbwm\Orange3-Network\
```

Comment: Issue resolved by installing Visual Studio Pro

Comment: Please post your issue to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-network/issues)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to settings, there go to "add-one" tab, select "Conda Install add-ons with conda".[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Finally the following command through the Anaconda Prompt worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge orange3-network
```