# I don't understand the answer on this site for installing the network option in Orange 3.28

Tags: orange

The instructions for using Options>Settigns>Add-ons in the post below are confusing.

[Orange Error when installing Network Add On](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/42689/orange-error-when-installing-network-add-on)

Is there a version of the "Network" addon that will install and work with Orangev3.28 (Python3) on Win10..?
Should I check the "Conda  install add-ons with conda" box, when I provide a pip command?
What is the proper pip command, neither of the above seem to work for installing the Network addons?  What is the default setting for Options>Settigns>Add-ons so I can set it correctly since I've messed with it.

I don't want to mess up my installation of Orange by setting this preference (setting) wrong, and block installation or operation of the other add-ons.